# Python sprite player control issue

Tags: pygame, sprite

I have a game that is supposed to allow two players to play. However, the second player does not move when the user pushes keys down.
(Plane2 is the second player)

```
class Plane(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("plane.gif")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        if not pygame.mixer:
            print "problem with sound"
        else:
            pygame.mixer.init()
            self.sndDing = pygame.mixer.Sound("ding.ogg")
            self.sndCrash = pygame.mixer.Sound("planeCrash.ogg")

    def update(self):
        mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.center = (mousex, mousey)

class Plane2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("plane2.gif")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 320
        self.rect.centery = 240

    def update(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.rect.centerx -= 8
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.rect.centerx += 8
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.rect.centery += 8
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.rect.centery -= 8
```

I tried moving the update function for Plane2 into the game loop, but that did not fix the problem.

```
def gameEndless():
    pygame.display.set_caption("Mail Pilot!")

    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    plane = Plane()
    island = Island()
    ocean = Ocean()
    scoreboard = Scoreboard()

    oceanSprites = pygame.sprite.Group(ocean)
    islandSprites = pygame.sprite.Group(island)
    planeSprite = pygame.sprite.Group(plane)
    scoreSprite = pygame.sprite.Group(scoreboard)
    bulletSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    enemySprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bossSprite = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bossWeaponSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    if gameType == "coop":
        scoreboard.lives = 10
        player2 = Plane2()
        planeSprite.add(player2)
```

I also tried making the second player its own sprite group, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Plane2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("plane2.gif")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 320
        self.rect.centery = 240

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.centery -= 8
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.centery += 8
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.centerx -= 8
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.centerx += 8
```

fixed code

Answer (score 0):

Create `update()` without `for` loop but with argument `event`

```
def update(self, event):
   if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
           self.rect.centerx -= 8
       elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
           self.rect.centerx += 8
       elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
           self.rect.centery += 8
       if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN
```

and in main loop use `update()` inside `for` loop

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    player1.update(event)
    player2.update(event)
```

This way you can handle different events in `update()` - not only `key` events but also `mouse` events or `user-defined` events.

Some people use name `handle_event` for this function. And they use `update()` to change this elements which doesn't need events - ie. set next frame of animation.

```
# --- events ---

for event in pygame.event.get():
    player1.handle_event(event)
    player2.handle_event(event)

# --- updates ---

player1.update()
player2.update()
```